# Is it possible to run initialization code just after the default init code runs?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscenedelegate

During iOS development I'm using a lot of classes which come from proprietary code which I have no access to. I want to run custom code that should run when this class is instantiated into an object, but I don't know how to, as I can't really override their init without knowing what parameters said init takes.

For example I am working on a `SceneDelegate` which subclasses `UIResponder` and `UIWindowSceneDelegate` and I want to have a property which should get initialized when the class is first instantiated, but I don't know how to.

At the moment I am just defaulting to defining the property as optional, initialize it in the method that will first use it, and write a whole bunch of code all around this class to handle the fact that it is unnecessarily optional.

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may try to make a class extension with your own init()?

```
extension SceneDelegate {
   init(someParam: ...) {
      ....
   }
}
```

Comment: But I would still have to have the normal init run, so the SceneDelegate continues to work nicely with iOS right? I don't know how to keep the normal init running as usual, and just run my custom init after it.